# Manual install of PHPMailer is failing in smtpSend due to undefined constant

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to set up PHPMailer 6.8.0 on PHP 8.0.8, using SMTP as my sending method.

When trying to send a message, I'm getting a fatal error of

`Undefined constant "PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer"`

This is occuring on line 2017 in PHPMailer, and the line in question is

`$header = PHPMailer . phpstatic::stripTrailingWSP($header) . static::$LE . static::$LE;`

This is being called in the postSend, and appears to be related to my installation.
In my application, I have PHPMailer installed manually (I would prefer not to use Composer).

PHPMailer is installed in the `PHPMailer` folder inside my `src` folder, and I have an emailer class which is also in the `src` folder, which is calling PHPMailer.

I am using the following `use` and `require` calls:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
require "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
require "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
```

PHPMailer *appears* to be imported correctly in my `emailer.php` source file, and all the SMTP properties are being populated correctly.

The fact that `PHPMailer` is being flagged as an undefined constant is making me think that this is a configuration issue, however I'm uncertain how to investigate this further. As this error is occuring within the `PHPMailer` source file, I would expect that it should be able to resolve correctly, which is why I suspect this is an issue in how I've set it up.

I would be grateful if anybody can point me in the right direction.

EDIT: The code for the emailer class is included below.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
require "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
require "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";

require 'config.php';


function send_email($toAddress, $subject, $body) {

    $phpmailer = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host = SMTP_Host;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = SMTP_Auth;
    $phpmailer->Port = SMTP_Port;
    $phpmailer->Username = SMTP_Username;
    $phpmailer->Password = SMTP_Password;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SecureMode;

    $phpmailer->setFrom(SMTP_SenderEmail, SMTP_SenderName);
    $phpmailer->addReplyTo(SMTP_SenderEmail, SMTP_SenderName);
    $phpmailer->addAddress($toAddress);

    $phpmailer->Subject = $subject;
    $phpmailer->isHTML = false;
    $phpmailer->Body = $body;

    if($phpmailer->send()){
        return 0;
    }else{
        $error = 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $phpmailer->ErrorInfo;
        error_log($error);

    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the emailer class?

Comment: @ibrahims Certainly. I'll add it now.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `SMTPSecure` value directly instead of using a constant.

Change this line `$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SecureMode;`

To this `$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;`

Comment: And please make sure you remove the constant ``SMTP_SecureMode``  from your config file.

Comment: I've tried that, however I'm still getting the same undefined constant error.

Comment: that error is coming from your ``config.php`` make sure you remove this ``define('SMTP_SecureMode', PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS)`` and confirm that all the constants used in ``emailer.php`` are correctly referenced as in config.php

Comment: I removed my last comment as it was wrong. The issue is that I had not placed the sources into PHPMailer/src, but directly into the PHPMailer folder within my project. What has thrown me is that this has worked in other projects before.